# What can I do to make synthesized speech segments add up to an exact duration?

Tags: filters, audio

I'm implementing a project which interacts with a Text To Speech library. It generates speech segments and then returns the waveform, which can be manipulated/saved according to my needs. Those segments must add up to a specific duration, but the speech generation does not have this type of accuracy. So that's why I'm asking this question here, because I think some audio manipulation might be needed. I'm completely new to this whole signal processing world, but I do understand that audio is (please correct me if I'm wrong) basically a wave. I've been watching/reading some resources and I know about the existence of filters, convolutions, and many different manipulations that can be applied to those segments in order to achieve a specific result. More specifically, I stumbled upon the Overlap And Add technique, which might help me solve the problem. I'm guessing that I need something related to time-stretching algorithms maybe. What I want from this post is, maybe someone could give me a headstart, some resource to look for in order to understand what I'm doing and keep researching until I can solve this problem. I'm completely open for any suggestions or hints that can help me accomplish this goal.

Please let me know if more details are necessary, so I can make the question more understandable.

**EDIT**:
In the problem at hand, I have several segments of text that must be synthesized at a specific duration (For example, the text "Hello everyone, this is your captain speaking", needs to be 3800ms in duration.) All of those segments, at the end, must match a total duration. As I said in the comments, I can pad the generated waveforms that take less time to synthesize, but I have no idea on what to do with the segments that take more time to generate (As another example the sentence "I'm studying signal processing" has a 4125ms duration when it should've had 3975ms). That's the problem I'm trying to solve.
I'm more than open to edit this question as many times as possible to make the problem understandable!

Comment: Are you looking to adjust all the segments so as to have the length of the longest segment in a batch of segments?

Comment: So, what I'm actually looking for is a suggestion on how to deal with segments that take longer to synthesize. With segments generated in a smaller duration than expected, I can pad the generated waveform to match the desired length. All of the segments in total must take add up to a specific duration

Comment: Can you please edit your post and be more specific on what you are asking? Perhaps including an example (?)